# How do I use paintEvent on a QVideoWidget with transparency?

Tags: c++, qt, rtsp, qpainter, qvideowidget

I'm working on qt5 (C +).
I use QVideoWidget to play rtsp video stream. I wanted to draw any signatures with QPainter on the displayed video. However, I obscure the video while drawing. For example, as for the drawing area, I have given half of the QVideoWidget image.

example used:
[image: example used]

Tried adding an extra QLabel on QVideoWidget:

```
QLabel * label = new QLabel (ui-> videoWidget);
```

And then draw on the "label", but also cover the QVideoWidget.

I also added:

```
ui-> videoWidget-> setAttribute (Qt :: WA_X11OpenGLOverlay);
```

But then the transparency extends all the way to the desktop of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the transparency of the item that you want to draw and not the transparency of the QVideoWidget.